# Cannot find symbol method name error

Tags: windows, methods

```
   /**
    * Returns a string describing the song object
    */
   public String toString()
   {
      return "Name of Song:" + this.title + "Sang by:" + getSingerName("") + this.getLanguageOfSong("") + "Alert needed:" + this.isAlertNeeded();
   }
```

Why I am getting the cannot find symbol method on `getSingerName` and `getLanguageOfSong`?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the rest of the class including the two methods you say are not working and then show us how you are calling the toString() method.

Comment: Unsure why you are passing blank Strings("") to the methods. That may be where your issue is.

Comment: Impossible to even guess, what programming language this is. Or how the error message really looks like. Or who is showing the error message. Please take the [tour] and see [ask] so that you can fix your question.

Comment: Not impossible.... it's probably Java. And the error is from calling a method the compiler cannot find.

Comment: @Mark: Why Java and not, say, C#? And if it's Java (or C#), why is the question tagged [tag:windows]? This is a case where reading [ask] is required.

Comment: @IInspectable Agreed 100% on reading How to Ask a question. Just disagreeing with your statements about "impossible to guess" the programming language and not knowing what the error message is. :) Seems like this user isn't going to come back and edit the question anyways (or is unaware that these comments are even happening).